# How to determine if an IEnumerable has been evaluated?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm wondering how I could tell if my `IEnumerable<T>` has been loaded as a list in memory (i.e. has been evaluated)?

I want this check for checking only date portion of DateTime for my query:

```
private IEnumerable<AccDocumentItem> FilterDocumentItemDateFilter(IEnumerable<AccDocumentItem> accDocumentItems, FilterDocumentDate filterDocumentDate)
{   
    accDocumentItems =
    accDocumentItems.Where(x =>
            x.AccDocument.CreateDate >= filterDocumentDate.FromDocumentDate &&
            x.AccDocument.CreateDate <= filterDocumentDate.ToDocumentDate);
}
```

I know that in `LinqToEntity` we can use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` and obviously in `LinqToObject` we can get date portion of `DateTime` but the problem is that I don't know if my `IEnumerable` has been executed or not?

**Edit:**
I wanted do this:

```
private IEnumerable<AccDocumentItem> FilterDocumentItemDateFilter(IEnumerable<AccDocumentItem> accDocumentItems, FilterDocumentDate filterDocumentDate)
{   
    if(accDocumentItems as IList<AccDocumentItem> != null)
    {
        accDocumentItems =
    accDocumentItems.Where(x =>
            x.AccDocument.CreateDate.Date >= filterDocumentDate.FromDocumentDate &&
            x.AccDocument.CreateDate.Date <= filterDocumentDate.ToDocumentDate);
    }
    else
    {
        accDocumentItems =
    accDocumentItems.Where(x =>
            EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.AccDocument.CreateDate) >= filterDocumentDate.FromDocumentDate &&
            EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.AccDocument.CreateDate) <= filterDocumentDate.ToDocumentDate);
    }
}
```

(Thank you Tim Schmelter ;)

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve here - or what truncating to date only has to do with knowing whether the sequence has been evaluated or not.

Comment: Let's pretend IEnumerable has a EnumeratedAtLeastOnce Boolean property. What does it matter? "This this has been enumerated before, but I need the data." You'll enumerate it again regardless.

Comment: @JonSkeet If `IEnumerable` has been evaluated i want `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.AccDocument.CreateDate)` and if not i want to execute `x.AccDocument.CreateDate.Date`

Comment: So you want your query to do something different the second time it's evaluated? That's very odd. It sounds like you really need to take a step back and think about what you're trying to do...

Comment: I think you are trying to prematurely optimize. You can avoid multiple enumeration with something like `return _list ?? (_list = document.Where(...).ToList());` but now the result is fixed.

Comment: If `IList<T>` were not invariant, we could just pattern match `xyz is IList<object> arrayOrList` :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to cast it with the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
if (list != null)
{
    // it is a list or array
}
```

Comment: How about using "is" instead?

Comment: @MartinMilan: Maybe, using `as` has the advantage that he can use it as list or array, for example if he wants to use it's methods. Depends on  what OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: It makes little difference and now you have a List on hand!

Comment: Tim, I think OP meant to check whether first `MoveNext` call was made or not. not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Because IEnumerable is an interface, you have no idea how it is implemented under the hood. Even if you wrote the the Enumerating code, and in this case you didn't, you still have to bear in mind that at some point you might change the underlying concrete type (to a List, or Collection, or whatever)...

For that reason, you should only rely on what is offered by IEnumerable() itself, and I don't believe it does offer anything of use to you... So you're a bit stuck in my view.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly and error-prone way would be:

```
var firstIterFirstItem = accDocumentItems.FirstOrDefault();
var secondIterFirstItem = accDocumentItems.FirstOrDefault();

var isEvaluated = firstIterFirstItem != null && ReferenceEquals(firstIterFirstItem, secondIterFirstItem);
```

Will only work for the case where enumerable is a result of realization(*Select*, etc.), not filtering.